# Problems connecting to Parallels Oracle DB with Telnet on MacOSX

Tags: database, oracle, telnet, parallels

I'm trying to run a TELNET command from my Mac OSX to an Oracle DB that is based on a Windows 7 (Virtual machine using Parallels on same Mac) but I get this error:

> Connection closed by foreign host

I've already checked the Listener for Oracle and it is activated and listening to 127.0.0.1 on port 1251 and to the VM ipAddress 10.211.55.4 on port 1251

I can successfully run a:

> ping 10.211.55.4

I have verified that the port is LISTENING using

> netstat -a

And i have checked via services (in Windows) to see if the port is RUNNING... and it is.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: This is my first post so if anything is out of place please let me know...
I have checked various threads and none answer

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is port 1251 and not 1521 (the default port for Oracle) ?

Comment: Why connect to Oracle with telnet? If you want to check connectivity use `tnsping` tool instead (not sure is there a version for MacOS though and you need to have Oracle client installed as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help!
The problem was not the port. It was rather that for some odd reason (replicable... but odd) Oracle DB installed two instances on my Windows VM and the connections got crossed.
The way I solved this was by removing ALL listeners to BOTH DB's and then creating a new Listener to a single instance.